# What shot rotation has the most dps output for MM Hunter with T12-4 set bonus?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

AS - Arcane Shot

CS - Chimera Shot

KC - Kill Command

SS - Steady Shot

[[Cataclysm] 4.2 Marksmanship Guide](http://elitistjerks.com/f74/t112408-cataclysm_4_2_marksmanship_guide/)

With T11-4 set bonus i had CS glyph and used CS-ASx3-SSx4 rotation which had exactly 9 seconds duration and sometimes used one SS instead of AS to balance focus. With T12 i have 12.93% haste and 1.4 sec SS cast time with raid buffs. I removed CS glyph and use the same rotation CS-ASx3-SSx4 which is now has 9.6 seconds duration meaning that there is 0.4 second gap that i have to wait before CS goes off cooldown and only when i have to use fifth SS instead of AS, to balance focus, it fits perfectly, which happens even less frequently because of free KC every second rotation. The guide mentioned above doesn't give an option, but maybe i missed something. Is there any rotation that fits better and doesn't have that annoying 0.4 second gap?

P.S. It is not possible to reduce haste by much and use 378 level gear.

Comment: Haven't played my hunter in ages but elitistjerks.com would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

There's no stable rotation that could be described by single sentence. You can try installing [Faceshooter](http://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/info13739-FaceShooter.html) addon (rotation helper) and test if it will help you to increase dps.

Another viable alternative addon is [Ovale Spell Priority](http://wow.curseforge.com/addons/ovale/).